# Deleting nodes from a binary search tree

Tags: data-structures, binary-search-tree

I understand the idea when deleting a node that has two subtrees: I "erase" the node's value and replace it with either its predecessor from the left subtree's value or its successor from the right subtree's value, and then delete *that* node.

However, does it matter if I choose the successor from the right subtree or the predecessor from the left subtree? Or is either way valid as long as I still have a binary search tree after performing the deletion?

Comment: both types of deletion are valid

Answer (score 0):

Both ways to perform a delete operation are valid if the node has two children.

Remember that when you get either the in-order predecessor node or the in-order successor node, you must call the delete operation on that node.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter which one you choose to replace. In fact you may need both.

Look at the following BST.

```
    7    
   / \    
  4   10    
 / \   /    
1   5  8
 \
  3
```

To delete `1`, you need to replace `1` with *right* node `3`.

And to delete `10`, you need to replace `10` with *left* node `8`.